# Does lubuntu have an anti-blue light feature?

Tags: configuration, lubuntu

Does lubuntu have an anti-[blue light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_blue_light_technology) feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, at least you can use [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) on it — install the `redshift-gtk` package.

Some desktop environments such as GNOME have similar features built-in, I’m not sure Lubuntu’s does.

Answer (score 1):

You could also run a cron script with usage of `xcalib`, e.g.:

```
# reduce blue, add red
xcalib -a -blue 1.1 0 100  -red 0.95 0 100 
# reduce gamma
xcalib -a -gc 1.05
```